# Replace in a string doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I've written this function:

```js
function solution(input, markers) {
  let inputcopy = input;
  let regexstring = markers[0]+'.*?(?=\\\\n)';
  let regexp1 = new RegExp(regexstring, 'gm');

  return inputcopy.replace(regexp1,'a');
};
console.log(solution("apples, plums % and bananas\npears\noranges !applesauce", ["%", "!"]));
```

Function needs to return

```
apples, plums a\npears\noranges !applesauce
```

but it returns

```
apples, plums % and bananas\npears\noranges !applesauce
```

What should I change?

Comment: can you describe what the regex should do?

Comment: Side note (it's not the problem): A function *declaration* (like your `solution` above) doesn't have a `;` after it. Including it is harmless, because JavaScript ignores extra `;`, but it's not meant to be there.

Comment: You have two extra backslashes - you only need `\\n`, not `\\\\n` (fix that, and it works)

Comment: You're always using the first marker as a test subject - you should iterate the array of `markers`, and then you can check your RegEx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `\\\\n` to `\\n`. It should work.

```
function solution(input, markers) {
        let inputcopy = input;
        let regexstring = markers[0]+'.*?(?=\\n)';
        let regexp1 = new RegExp(regexstring, 'gm');

        return inputcopy.replace(regexp1,'a');
    };

    solution("apples, plums % and bananas\npears\noranges !applesauce", ["%", "!"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the end of string sign `$` and the multiline flag `m` together.

Otherwise, you do not need the multiline flag, but the right newline with only double backslashes `\\n`.

```js
function solution(input, markers) {
  let inputcopy = input;
  let regexstring = markers[0]+'.*$';
  let regexp1 = new RegExp(regexstring, 'gm');

  return inputcopy.replace(regexp1,'a');
}
console.log(solution("apples, plums % and bananas\npears\noranges !applesauce", ["%", "!"]));
//                    apples, plums   a          \npears\noranges !applesauce
```